# Swift 3: Show Tab Bar on an other ViewController

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using a tab bar which is connected to 3 `viewControllers`. What I want to do is when I click the some rows on my main `viewController`, I want to keep my tab bar for this page.

This is my main `viewController` on the tab bar:

[image: main view controller on tab bar]

When I click on a `tableView`'s row on the left side, I want to keep the tab bar on the other page in its place. I guess I have to do something in the `prepare for segue` function. What do you guys think?

Comment: use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458948/how-to-use-navigation-controller-inside-of-uitabbarcontroller-with-storyboard-on

Comment: I tried relationship segue as they told. but I need to pass some datas to my viewController and I can't give segue identifier when I choose relationship segue.

Comment: you use tabbar view controller with navigation controller so it's work

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1 use this example