# TabBarController issue

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabBar Controller with 2 tabs: firstVC, secondVC. And when tabBarController appears i want to see on the screen this tabBar controller with 2 tabs and active controller(called main) not from this tabs. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you add a storyboard layout of what your are trying to achieve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Navigation Controller inside of UITabBarController with Storyboard on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458948/how-to-use-navigation-controller-inside-of-uitabbarcontroller-with-storyboard-on)

Comment: I mean that i want to have 2 tabbarItems (firstVC, secondVC) and main VC as initial (selected) VC which is not showing in tabbarItem but currently active.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
You can embed those 2 tabs in navigationControllers. Each of the 2 tabs will have its own stack of viewControllers.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29459123/8600207) for a detailed description.

Comment: I mean that i want to have 2 tabbarItems (firstVC, secondVC) and main VC as initial (selected) VC which is not showing in tabbarItem but currently active.

Comment: Your answer just about push... but main goal of question is about mainVC which must be hidden in tabbarItems.