# Why UINavigationBar isn't shown if reenter UITabBarController()?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a viewcontroller of `UITabBarController()` which is a **rootviewcontroller** of a `UINavigationController`. There are three **subChildViewController** in `UITabBarController`. If I selected non-first segment and exist the `UITabBarController`, then I enter the `UITabBarController` again, the `navigationBar` won't shown. It only repro in iOS version between iOS 11.0 and 11.2.

Comment: post some code. if its a gif or video then it will be fine. Are you hiding navigation bar somewhere?

Comment: give us some gif of your storyboard and see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458948/how-to-use-navigation-controller-inside-of-uitabbarcontroller-with-storyboard-on). It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

A tabbar controller contains an array for x view controllers. Each of the view controllers may or may not be embedded in a nav bar controller.

The tab bar controller shouldn’t be embedded in a nav bar.

Comment: The logical is like this: VC1 which is the root of a navigationController. Push VC2 into the navigationController in the viewDidLoad of VC1. the view of TabBarViewController is a subView of VC2.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Mark, TabBar shouldn't be embedded in a navBar, but it works the other way, with a navBar able to be embedded into each tab of a tabBar.

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, why you have a navBar before the tabBar, but if your goal is something like a login page that then goes to the TabBar, you can get from the tabBar back to the original ViewController via a button or some other action that calls code similar to the following:
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate! as! AppDelegate
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewStoryBoardName") as! SpecificViewController
    appDelegate.window?.set(rootViewController: vc)